# Pipewire on Ubuntu (20.04) playing audio on both speaker and headphone port

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, laptop, headphones, pipewire

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, albeit with some changes to the regular distribution. I installed the minimal Ubuntu server and then got what I wanted from some repositories. For example, I got the Kubuntu repositories and then KDE Neon on top of it. All of this came with pulseaudio by default and I wanted to try out pipewire since it works great on my other laptop with Arch.
So I followed a guide and got pipewire working but everytime I reboot and boot without the headphones already plugged in, if I then decide to plug them in, I don't have a way to separate the laptop speakers from the headphone output without restarting the pipewire service.

I don't really know how to diagnose this so I'm asking here while googling myself some solutions, hoping some of you might have insight to give me. My laptop is the HP-15s-fq4008np, the audio driver seems to be the following: driver=sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a KDE/Neon forum.  *KDE Neon and Kubuntu do share some support sites, alas this is not one of them*

Comment: KDE Neon uses a Ubuntu base, but then packages from later non-LTS releases to provide a new Qt5 & KF5 stack as required by later KDE Plasma desktops... KDE Neon is **not** a Ubuntu system, but a mix of many Ubuntu releases plus 3rd party non-Ubuntu packages.

Comment: Do the packages interfere with pulseaudio/pipewire? I don't think so since I did not see any changes to audio when updating the system with the neon repositories. I'm seeing related issues with pipewire, wireplumber and pulseaudio even on Ubuntu (non-flavoured). Why can't this be here? Just because of the additional context I gave?